# How does Steam set a game's background in the Library?

Tags: steam

Lately, I realized, that the background of a game in the Steam Library changes from time to time, and I swear, I once even recognized the background somehow from a scene I've been to in a game.

So, how does Steam set the game's background?

Does it secretly take screen-shots while I am playing, or use preset images, or is it just random?

Comment: It uses preset images, but as soon as you made screenshots (via F12 usually), they will be used. At least that's what I experienced with Arkham Asylum

Comment: @TobiasKienzler It definitely also uses your own screenshots. I took a random one of a dead bunny in skyrim (I'm a monster, what can I say) and it appeared as my background to guilt trip me. I'd add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Alex done, I just thought it's not "prove" enough

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The background images for a game in your library (and also for the game's store page!*) are taken from the publisher / store page <sup>†</sup> and your gallery of **recent** screenshots.<sup>‡</sup>

---

* *If no background image was specified by whoever made the store page, it simply chooses the right-most screenshot from the game's gallery. Methodology: Looked at very old games on steam, then some new / popular games. Results held up to prediction on every case attempted.*

† *Images are taken from the store page only in the case that no images have specified by the publisher, that is.*

‡ *Methodology: I have some old pictures of The Guild 2 in my gallery, about half a year old. After clicking back and forth for new images in my library about 30 times, they've yet to show up as a background for the game.*

*To see if a newer picture would appear as a background, I loaded the game, and took a screenshot and uploaded to the cloud. It showed up the first attempt.*

*Similarly, taking another screenshot* ***without*** *uploading to the cloud also resulted in that image being posted as a background on first attempt.*

[image: A screenshot of my steam library, showing a background image for The Guild II]

[image: A screenshot of The Guild II's store page, featuring the same background image in two places.]

Answer (score 8):

Steam doesn't take screenshots by itsef. It uses those available for each game (including those you take yourself), when you select it in the library.

Comment: negative, it definitely used the ones I made from Arkham Asylum (this is of course only valid if you take screenshots with Steam's overlay screenshot tool)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Yes, I could have said it more clearly. (Now fixed.)

Comment: ah yes, now I get what you meant

Answer (score 6):

It uses preset images, but as soon as you made screenshots (via F12 usually), they will be used. At least that's what I experienced with Arkham Asylum